# Reactivity problem with mapGetters only on first load

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, store, vue-reactivity

I am using the `mapGetters` helper from VueX but i have some problem only on the first load of the page, it's not reactive... 
Let me show you :

my html template triggering the change :

```html
<input type="number" value="this.inputValue" @change="this.$store.dispatch('setInputValue', $event.target.value)">
```

my store receiving the value

```
{
    state: {
        appValues: {
            inputValue: null
        },
    },
    getters: {
        getInputValue: (state) => {
            return state.appValues.inputValue;
        },
    },
    mutations: {
        setInputValue(state, value) {
            state.appValues.inputValue = value;
        },
    },
    actions: {
        setInputValue(context, payload) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                context.commit('setInputValue', payload);
                resolve();
            });
        },
    }
}
```

and then my component listening the store :

```
import {mapGetters} from 'vuex';

computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
        inputValue: 'getInputValue',
    }),
}
watch: {
    inputValue: {
        deep: true,
        immediate: true,
        handler(nVal, oVal) {
            console.log("inputValue", nVal, oVal);
        }
    },
}
```

So now, when i first load the page I get this console.log `"inputValue" null undefined` which is totally normal because as I have nothing in my store it gaves me the default value *null*.

But now it's the weird part. I start changing the input value and I don't have nothing appearing in my console. Nothing is moving...

Then I reload the page and on the load I get this console.log `"inputValue" 5 undefined` (5 is the value I entered previously) so as you can see, when I was changing the input previously, it was well keeping the value in the store but the computed value was not updating itself...

Ans now, when I change the value of the input I have my console log like this `"inputValue" 7 5` so it's working as I would like it to work from the start...

What do I do wrong? Why on the first load the computed value not reactive?

Thanks for your answers...

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to solve this issue is to store a local variable with a watcher, and then update vuex when the local is changed:

On your component:

```html
<input type="number" v-model="value">
```

```
data() {
    return {
        value: ''
    };
},

computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
        inputValue: 'getInputValue'
    })
}

watch: {
    value(value){
        this.$store.dispatch('setInputValue', value);
    },

    inputValue(value) {
        console.log('inputValue', value);
    }
},

created() {
    // set the initial value to be the same as the one in vuex
    this.value = this.inputValue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you, I already did this and yes it works, but the problem is more like I have tons of variables in my store so if I have to duplicate each of them it will be a waste of time... And mapGetters should work fine...

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/vuex-store-ne3ol

Your mistake is, you are using `this` keyword in template. One shouldn't use `this` in template code.

```
<input
      type="number"
      value="inputValue"
      @change="$store.dispatch('setInputValue', $event.target.value)"
    >
```

> Bonus tip: It is redundant to use a getter to return the default state
>   if you can just use `mapState` to return the state.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it didn't work in my case, it doesn't change anything at all ... -_- Oh and btw, if I use mapGetter it's because in my real project (the code I gave is just a resume of all the code i have) the getters is important because I can make some conditions and logic that I couldn't do in the State

Comment: @SimonTrichereau Cool, if you want to use the getter to get conditional data is state. Then it's fine. Could you create a code sample in codepen or codesandbox so I help you solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few small mistakes in the template. It should be this:

```html
<input type="number" :value="inputValue" @change="$store.dispatch('setInputValue', $event.target.value)">
```

I've removed the `this.` in a couple of places and put a `:` out the front of `value`. Once I make these changes everything works as expected. The `this.$store` was causing console errors for me using Vue 2.6.10.

I would add that you're using the `change` event. This is the standard DOM `change` event and it won't fire until the field blurs. So if you just start typing you won't see anything happen in the console. You'd be better off using `input` if you want it to update on every keystroke. Alternatively you could use `v-model` with a getter and setter (see https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html#two-way-computed-property).

My suspicion is that when you were reloading the page that was triggering the change event because it blurred the field.

Comment: It was totally my bad, I didn't write the code really well here... BUT it's not changing anything... My real problem is from a `<select>` tag indeed, but I want not to write the options and everything, I tryed with an input and same problem so I decided to put the input way in my problem to be more conciliant...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so ... I found the problem and it was not relative to my examples, I can't really explain why, but I'll try to explain how :

In my store I have the next method :

```
mutations: {
    deleteAppValues(state) {
        state.appValues = null;
    }
}
```

I was using this one on the Logout, or when the user first comes on the pageand was not logged-in... So what was going-on?

1. The User first load the page, the store is initializing well, and the index `inputValue` is initialized with null value, so it exists...
2. ... But as the User is not logged, I destroy the store so now the inputValue is not equals to null, **it just doesn't exist**...
3. Trying to use `mapGetters` on something that don't exists, the reactivity won't work, so if I dispatch a change, the store key will be created, but as the mapGetters was initialized with an inexisting key, it doesn't listen the reactivity...
4. After reloading the page, the key now exists in the store so the getter can be attached to it and so now everything working fine...

This is exactly the explaination of what was going wrong about my code... So to make it works fine, I just changed my destruction mutation to :

```
mutations: {
    deleteAppValues(state) {
        state.appValues = {
            inputValue: null,
        };
    }
}
```

Like this, the inputValue key of the store object will always exists and so the getter won't lose his reactivity...

I tryed to make a simple concise question but that made me forgot the bad part of my code, sorry.